# Complete file line by line reading dates

Tags: awk, sed, fortran

I have a text file containing 2 columns. The first one has DATES (DD/MM/YYYY) and the second one, numbers. It looks like this:

```
15/01/1945 105.0
16/01/1945   4.2
17/01/1945   3.0
31/01/1945  12.0
01/02/1945   3.0
02/02/1945 125.0
05/02/1945   0.3
```

And I need to fill the file with this conditions:

1. First date 01/01/1945
2. Last date 31/12/2021
3. Dates must be consecutive, with a difference of one day between lines
4. If there is a missing date, we have to complete the line with the correct date and the number -99.0

So, the final file should look like this:

```
01/01/1945 -99.0
02/01/1945 -99.0
03/01/1945 -99.0
04/01/1945 -99.0
05/01/1945 -99.0
06/01/1945 -99.0
07/01/1945 -99.0
08/01/1945 -99.0
09/01/1945 -99.0
10/01/1945 -99.0
11/01/1945 -99.0
12/01/1945 -99.0
13/01/1945 -99.0
14/01/1945 -99.0
15/01/1945 105.0
16/01/1945   4.2
17/01/1945   3.0
18/01/1945 -99.0
19/01/1945 -99.0
20/01/1945 -99.0
21/01/1945 -99.0
22/01/1945 -99.0
23/01/1945 -99.0
24/01/1945 -99.0
25/01/1945 -99.0
26/01/1945 -99.0
27/01/1945 -99.0
28/01/1945 -99.0
29/01/1945 -99.0
30/01/1945 -99.0
31/01/1945  12.0
01/02/1945   3.0
02/02/1945 125.0
03/02/1945 -99.0
04/02/1945 -99.0
05/02/1945   0.3
06/02/1945 -99.0
07/02/1945 -99.0
...
30/12/2021 -99.0
31/12/2021 -99.0
```

I have tried by using a fortran program but it doesn't work. I think that maybe using awk or sed or both.

This is what I get when I read Ed's script:

```
meteo@poniente:/datos$ cat awk.script
#!/bin/bash
cat tst.awk
awk { dates2vals[$1] = $2 }
END {
    begDate = "01/01/1945"
    endDate = "31/12/2000"
    begSecs = mktime(gensub("(.*)/(.*)/(.*)","\\3 \\2 \\1 12 00 00",1,begDate))
    daySecs = 24 * 60 * 60
    for (curSecs=begSecs; curDate!=endDate; curSecs+=daySecs) {
        curDate = strftime("%d/%m/%Y",curSecs)
        print curDate, (curDate in dates2vals ? dates2vals[curDate] : "-99.0")
    }
}
```

And this is what I get when I run Ed's script:

```
meteo@poniente:/datos$ ./tst.awk
01/01/1946   3.0
02/01/1946  14.2
...
14/11/2021   0.0
15/11/2021   0.0
16/11/2021   0.0
17/11/2021   0.0
18/11/2021   0.0
19/11/2021   0.0
20/11/2021   0.0
21/11/2021   0.0
22/11/2021  54.1
23/11/2021 -99.0
24/11/2021  27.4
25/11/2021   0.0
29/11/2021   0.0
30/11/2021   0.0
awk: li­ne ord.:1: {
awk: line ord.:1:  ^ unexpected newline or end of string
./awk.script: li­ne 4: END: command not found
./awk.script: li­ne 5: begDate: command not found
./awk.script: li­ne 6: endDate: command not found
./awk.script: li­ne 7: syntax error near unexpected element `('
./awk.script: li­ne 7: `    begSecs = mktime(gensub("(.*)/(.*)/(.*)","\\3 \\2 \\1 12 00 00",1,begDate))'
meteo@poniente:/datos$
```

Comment: Could you possibly fix your question and use code formatting, so we can more easily copy-paste your examples?

Comment: are the dates in the input always consecutive ?

Comment: Yes, they are always consecutives, but there are missing dates. Files are always in order and the oldest date is always the first.

Answer (score 3):

Try creating your long list, using `seq` (in epoch seconds: start, delta=1day, end) and `date`'s `-f` option, with the default values `-99.0`, then replace where possible with `awk`:

```
seq -f"@%.0f" -- -788878800 86400 1640905200 | date -uf- +"%d/%m/%Y -99.0" | awk 'FNR==NR {A[$1] = $2; next} $1 in A {$2 = A[$1]} 1' file - 
01/01/1945 -99.0
02/01/1945 -99.0
.
.
.

14/01/1945 -99.0
15/01/1945 105.0
16/01/1945 4.2
17/01/1945 3.0
18/01/1945 -99.0
19/01/1945 -99.0
20/01/1945 -99.0
21/01/1945 -99.0
22/01/1945 -99.0
23/01/1945 -99.0
24/01/1945 -99.0
25/01/1945 -99.0
26/01/1945 -99.0
27/01/1945 -99.0
28/01/1945 -99.0
29/01/1945 -99.0
30/01/1945 -99.0
31/01/1945 12.0
01/02/1945 3.0
02/02/1945 125.0
03/02/1945 -99.0
04/02/1945 -99.0
05/02/1945 0.3
06/02/1945 -99.0
07/02/1945 -99.0
08/02/1945 -99.0
09/02/1945 -99.0
10/02/1945 -99.0
.
.
.
28/12/2021 -99.0
29/12/2021 -99.0
30/12/2021 -99.0
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean. How does RudiC's command not work?

Comment: To edit your file in place, you need to add ` > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file`.

Comment: Hi, thanks!! I already had the a file with the long list that is LIST.DAT. In that file a have, line by line, dates between 01/01/1945 and 31/12/2021. How can I use the awk order supossing that I have these 2 fles (LIST.DAT and INPUT.txt) and writing -99.0 if there is a missing date in the input file?

Comment: Note that `-f` (that accepts a file with list of input dates; some other `date` implementations have a `-f` option for something else) is a GNU-specific `date` extension.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk for time functions:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{ dates2vals[$1] = $2 }
END {
    begDate = "01/01/1945"
    endDate = "31/12/2021"
    begSecs = mktime(gensub("(.*)/(.*)/(.*)","\\3 \\2 \\1 12 00 00",1,begDate))
    daySecs = 24 * 60 * 60
    for (curSecs=begSecs; curDate!=endDate; curSecs+=daySecs) {
        curDate = strftime("%d/%m/%Y",curSecs)
        print curDate, (curDate in dates2vals ? dates2vals[curDate] : "-99.0")
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file | wc -l
28124
$ awk -f tst.awk file | head -5
01/01/1945 -99.0
02/01/1945 -99.0
03/01/1945 -99.0
04/01/1945 -99.0
05/01/1945 -99.0
$ awk -f tst.awk file | tail -5
27/12/2021 -99.0
28/12/2021 -99.0
29/12/2021 -99.0
30/12/2021 -99.0
31/12/2021 -99.0
$ awk -f tst.awk file | grep -v '99.0'
15/01/1945 105.0
16/01/1945 4.2
17/01/1945 3.0
31/01/1945 12.0
01/02/1945 3.0
02/02/1945 125.0
05/02/1945 0.3
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! I have tried your awk command, but I get and error: Syntax error: `(' unexpected in line begSecs = mktime(gensub("(.*)/(.*)/(.*)","\\3 \\2 \\1 12 00 00",1,begDate),1)

Comment: If you don't tell me what the error is then I can't help you debug it. Please copy/paste the error message into a comment and also tell me the output of `awk --version`. My best guess is you aren't using GNU awk as I said is required.

Comment: Sorry. My awk version is GNU Awk 3.1.6. It is an old computer with no Internet connection

Comment: I have checked again, and RudiC's command works perfectly!! Thanks all of you!!

Comment: @David You're welcome. Yea, your version of gawk is 13 years out of date, we're now on version 5.1.1. My script should still work though as mktime(), strftime(), and gensub() (the 3 gawk extension functions I used) were all introduced in 3.1 but **maybe** you'd just have to remove the final ,1 utc-flag from the calls to mktime() and/or strftime() that I always add out of habit but you don't need for your case. I edited my answer to remove those flags, if that doesn't fix it then idk what the problem could be unless you copy/pasted wrong.

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for your help. Yes, my awk version is quite old. And it is working in an old laptop with Ubuntu 10.04 that I haven't used for ages and I had to rescue some weeks ago. I would like to update, but I'm afraid of...I have tried your code and I get this error message: ./extraccion_precipitacion.script: li­ne 104: error sintactico cerca del elemento inesperado `('
./extraccion.script: li­nea 104: `    begSecs = mktime(gensub("(.*)/(.*)/(.*)","\\3 \\2 \\1 12 00 00",1,begDate))'
It is the same error that I got when I used the first version of your code. Do you have any guesses?

Comment: @David my guess is you aren't executing the script in my answer as that error message says it's from line 104 but my script is only 11 lines long and the message itself doesn't actually make sense for any gawk version to output. Please copy/paste exactly the script in my answer and run it exactly as shown in my answer and then let me know if you have any problems with that.

Comment: your code was part of a longer script, that's why the error messege was in line 104. Anyway, I've written your code in a new file just with it. And I got the same messege but now we can see where it fails:
22/11/21   0.0
30/11/21   0.0
./awk.script: li­ne 10: error sintactico cerca del elemento inesperado (' ./extraccion.script: li­nea 10:  begSecs = mktime(gensub("(.*)/(.*)/(.*)","\\3 \\2 \\1 12 00 00",1,begDate))'
And the error appears when the script arrives to the last line of the file, that is "30/11/21 0.0" and it doesn't do any of the orders of the awk code, just the cat order

Comment: The error message says it's at line 10 but prints the contents of line 5 of my script so you're still not just executing the script I posted and without seeing the script you ARE running I can't help you debug the problems with it.

Comment: Please execute `cat -v awk.script` on your terminal and copy/paste the result into your question along with excatly the contents of your screen when you try to run it including the command line and the output including the exact error message. If you do that I'll take a look to see if I can spot what you're doing wrong. Don't post it in a comment where it can't be formatted - edit your question to add this info to the bottom of it.